# Is this famous Michael Jackson dance move inspired by The Wizard of Oz (1939)?

Tags: the-wizard-of-oz

Is there an evidence that this famous Michael Jackson dance move is inspired by the movie The Wizard of Oz (1939)? With evidence I mean an interview or something like that.

In The Wizard of Oz there is a scene in which the Tin Man is dancing. You can rewatch it in this video:

[image: Michael Jackson Dance Move]
[image: Scene from Wizard of Oz]

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if MJ was actually inspired by __Charlie Chaplin__, who did "The Lean" in __[A Day's Pleasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F63McN9tpTI&t=15m55s)__ (1919). - MJ was known to be [a big fan](http://www.mjworld.net/news/2014/04/16/michaels-tribute-to-charlie-chaplin/) of Charlie Chaplin.

Comment: Now for me it sounds more convincing that the dance move is inspired by Charlie Chaplin, too! Maybe there is an even better proof for that.

Comment: @Oliver_C: I'd add that as an answer to be honest. There's a fair amount of evidence to show Chaplin was one of his biggest influences (with his attire in the video all a tribute to Fred Astaire)

Answer (score 3):

"The lean" goes back to [circus performers in the late 19th century](http://www.elusiveshadow.com/37-contenu-en-francais/dossiers/enquetes/2148-le-lean-de-smooth-criminal-comment-michael-jackson-se-penche-en-avant), for instance [Harry "Little Titch" Relph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkEUHawaAZ4).

> Le Lean n'est pas né dans le clip de Smooth Criminal mais dans les
>   cirques de la fin du 19ème siècle, peut-être même avant. L'un des plus
>   anciens numéros de lean connus était pratiqué par un artiste du nom de
>   Harry Relph, plus connu sous le pseudonyme de "Little Tich". C'était
>   un comique de music-hall qui incarnait une multitude de personnages et
>   était célèbre pour sa "Big Boot Dance", une chorégraphie faisant appel
>   à une paire de chaussures de 70 cm de long... Cette danse a même donné
>   lieu à un film de 1900 signé Clément Maurice, "Little Tich et ses Big
>   Boots", dont Jacques Tati dira : "c'est la base de tout ce qui a été
>   réalisé à l'écran en matière de comédie". Lorsqu'il s'est retiré de la
>   scène, Harry Relph a fait don de ses chaussures à Sacha Guitry.

Paraphrased:

> The Lean was born in the circuses at the end of the 19th century,
>   possibly even earlier. One of its earliest known performers was Harry
>   Relph, aka "Little Tich", a music hall comedian known for his "Big
>   Boots Dance" with 70cm long shoes. This act is the source of the 1900
>   movie by Clément Maurice, "Little Tich and his Big Boots", of which
>   Jacques Tati claims "this is the start of comedy cinema." After
>   Relph's retirement, Sacha Guitry inherited the shoes.

Buster Keaton [also performed it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_RMB3N3fCY).

Comment: You might want to translate or at least paraphrase that quote there. Otherwise you don't need to quote it at all and could just let it remain as a link.